# Kafka stream - define a retention policy for a changelog

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I use Kafka Streams for some aggregations of a TimeWindow.
I'm interested only in the final result of each window, so I use the .suppress() feature which creates a changelog topic for its state.

The retention policy configuration for this changelog topic is defined as "compact" which to my understanding will keep at least the last event for each key in the past.

The problem in my application is that keys often change. This means that the topic will grow indefinitely (each window will bring new keys which will never be deleted).

Since the aggregation is per window, after the aggregation was done, I don't really need the "old" keys.

Is there a way to tell Kafka Streams to remove keys from previous windows?

For that matter, I think configuring the changelog topic retention policy to "compact,delete" will do the job (which is available in kafka according to this: [KIP-71](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-71%3A+Enable+log+compaction+and+deletion+to+co-exist), [KAFKA-4015](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-4015).

But is it possible to change the retention policy so using the Kafka Streams api?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`suppress()` operator sends tombstone messages to the changelog topic if a record is evicted from its buffer and sent downstream. Thus, you don't need to worry about unbounded growth of the topic. Changing the compaction policy might in fact break the guarantees that the operator provide and you might loose data.

Comment: Thank you. According to what I understand, the tombstone record will prevent the state store (of Kafka Streams) to grow indefinitely. But would it prevent also the kafka topic itself to grow ?

Comment: Stores don't really have (and don't need) a tombstone concept, because for stores it's possible to delete records. Tombstones *are* in fact a Kafka concept for compacted topics: during compaction, tombstones are interpreted as deleted and all messages before a tombstone with the same key as the tombstone message are deleted (including the tombstone message itself).

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks again.

Comment: What if the topology does not use the `suppress()` operator. Is there a way to manually send a tombstone message to the changelog topic?

Comment: For windowed aggregations, you don't need to use tombstones for the changelog. Windowed-changelog topics are configured with "compact,delete" strategy and drop old windows after they expired.